# How to set 'fog_public' value on model when using carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using rails with **carrierwave** gem to upload file. Problem is the customer want these files must have *is_public* attribute and this one will decide the filed upload can be readable or not (S3 stored).

My solution now is setup 2 folders on S3 to store and set readable for the *public* one.

**image_uploader.rb**

```
  def store_dir
    if self.model.is_public
      "images/public/#{model.id}"
    else
      "images/private/#{model.id}"
    end
  end
```

**Bucket Policy file on S3**

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/images/public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**config/initializers/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
  config.fog_public = false
```

But I don't want to config S3 Bucket Policy every time because my product will be sold for many customer. I just want to setup   *fog_public* attribute config depend on *is_public* value in my **image_uploader.rb** file, like that:

**image_uploader.rb**

```
before_save :set_is_public

private

def set_is_public
  fog_public = self.model.is_public 
end
```

It has any way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: is this uploader mounted into a rails model?you should set `is_public` there instead. The question is when do you want it to be set.

Answer (score 1):

My solution so far is

**image_uploader.rb**

```
  before :store, :set_is_public

  def set_is_public file
    self.fog_public = self.model.is_public
  end
```

but problem is when I edit the is_public attribute, this callback cannot be called